# How to change the color of git log within the gitconfig file?

Tags: git

There have been many answers on stackoverflow regarding how to do this on the command line, my question is how to do this in my **gitconfig** file.

For the `git branch`, I can change the color of the: current branch, the local branch and the remote branch with this syntax:

```
[color "branch"]
    current = green reverse
    local = green
    remote = green
```

[image]

Similarly, for the `git log` command: I can change the color of the: branch, remoteBranch, tags, HEAD and commit via the below syntax.

```
[color "decorate"]
    branch = blue bold
    remoteBranch = green
    tag = green
    stash = green
    HEAD = green
[color "diff"]
    commit = red
```

[image]

For all of these setting, I picked this information from the man pages of `git-config` https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-color. But I've been looking through it, and through stackoverflow and I cannot find the information to change the color for the following fields in `git-log`:

1. Author
2. Date
3. Commit Message (not commit hash)

Ultimately, I want to have this level of control over my git log message:
[image]

Comment: My guess you don't want to here: you cannot customize those fields' colors. The screenshot you provided is probably using some third party tool.

Comment: The screenshot is after using `bat` on it. It is a third party tool, I wanted to find a way to do it internally with git.

Comment: I do not think there is one. Nothing like this is ever mentioned in the official git documentation.